# Presence of Muhammad in Battle Of Karbala

Tags: islamic-events

According to some Hadith book written by some scholar,During the Battle Of Karbala, Salma went to visit Muhammad's wife Umme Salamah. In the Convesation between them,Salama told she had seen Allah's Messenger with dust on his head and beard. She asked him what was the matter and he replied, `I have just been present at the slaying of al-Husayn.' Does such thing really happened ? If Muhammad present in that battle field why he didn't save Al-Hussain ?

Comment: If you're looking for the confirmation of a hadith, you really could show more research effort than "some Hadith book written by some scholar".

Answer (score 0):

First, the significance of this is to prove that the prophet actually have seen his grandson in the battle of Karbala, this means that he knew what happened to him, who killed him and everything happened there.

Now, your problem is that you feel that Al Hussain was actually in trouble to be *saved*. Shia believe that Al-Housain was able to survive but he didn't he chose to sacrifice his life to save Islam. please read more about battle of Karbala .

Comment: Thanks for the source..I wish i read this if i know Arabic...Ya actually in the battle field according to shia tradition,A void from the skies says "We are satisfied with your deeds and sacrifices". Please clarify me What is "WE"..I mean who and all satisfied with his sacrifice to save islam ?

Comment: @Warrior sorry for that source, this guy has something in his description about karbala please read it: http://islam.stackexchange.com/users/67/battle-of-karbala

Comment: @user689 and warriorprince,  'we' may be the voice of God himself. becuse it came from sky, voice of 'all muslims' coming from the sky doesnot make sense

Comment: MAKZ.."Voice of God himself"..There is only one prophet right..I can't able to find the meaning behind "WE"

Comment: @Warrior I think I understood this wrong, MAKZ is right. In arabic 'We' signifies the greatness of god.